# Vue3 + Tailwind: @apply {prop}

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm looking for a way to apply a tailwind class from a variable/prop. something like:

```scss
<style lang="scss">
.app-icon {
  svg {
    @apply v-bind(extraClass)
  }
}
</style>
```

`extraClass` is a prop.
This results in error: "The `v-bind(extraClass)` class does not exist."

I have also tried another approach:

```js
<template>
    <div class="flex items-center app-icon" :class="'[*]:' + $props.extraClass">
        <n-icon v-bind="$props" :size="width" :component="iconComponent"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

This code injected the `extraClass` to all it's children but it does not move into `n-icon`s children, so the `svg` i'm targeting is not effected.